# The styled-jsx does not render the style when the Browser has js disabled (Rollup and styled-jsx)

Tags: next.js, rollup, styled-jsx

please, can you help me?

I'm working on a blog project and one of the requirements is that the blog works even if the browser has javascript disabled. When using the project "https://github.com/dionatanaraujo/rollup-styled-jsx" a fork of "https://github.com/Tomekmularczyk/rollup-styled-jsx", we noticed that when disabling the browser javascript the components are not carrying styling.

How simulate the error:

1. Enter in the root project and run `npm install` and then `npm run build:prod`
2. Enter in the demo project `cd demo` and run `npm install` and then `npm run dev`
3. Access the browser http://localhost:3000, go to settings and disable javascript.
4. Note that the styles will not be loaded.

Please, is there something wrong or missing in this configuration so that the styles work correctly when javascript is disabled?

Component library with js enabled (work's fine):
[image]

Component library with js disabled (styles don't work):
[image]

The project that is in / demo and was built using Next.js to work with SSR. Please, if anyone can help with that it would be very rewarding.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a problem, the documentation says that when you disable javascript in dev mode css will not be loaded but in production it will. try to deploy your blog on vercel and disable javascript, you will then see that the css will still be loaded